# managing akka one-off actors

Tags: scala, akka

I am playing around with actors. So far none of my actors have states so I have been creating one-off actors (using system.actorOf or context.actorOf) and never refer to the ActorRef again after sending a message. Is this a good practice for my use-case? Should I manually kill them using `context.stop()` once my actor is done processing the event?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not entirely clear to me from your question, but presuming the intent is that your once-off actors are doing some work, then sending a message with the results back to the original caller, after which they have nothing left to do, they should send a stop message to themselves after sending the response:

```
...do work...
...assemble response...
caller ! response
context.stop(self)
```

Or, especially if there is a chance the actor's standard flow could fail, you could have the actor set up a `PoisonPill` call to itself via the scheduler (or the spawning parent could do this). Eg.:

```
import scala.concurrent.duration.FiniteDuration

class SingleJobActor(max_time_to_live: FiniteDuration) extends Actor {

  override def preStart {
    import context.dispatcher
    context.system.scheduler.scheduleOnce(max_time_to_live, self, PoisonPill)
  }

  ...rest of actor...
}
```

Comment: You got it! Thats the gist of my receive method. The only thing that was missing was the `context.stop` call. It wasn't clear to me from the documentation that I had to do that since the idea of a one-off actor was mentioned only once